# Index the embedding matrix in order to get the the corresponding vector of each token-id in a new matrix

Tags: python, numpy

i have two matrices, the token-id matrix [5,10] and the embedding matrix [31,15].
I want to index the embedding matrix in order to get a new matrix [M,N,D] where essentially for each token id in the first matrix we will get the corresponding vector from the embedding matrix.Can anyone help?  I want to work with numpy operations.
That' s my code:

First one (is a token-id matrix [5,10])

```
import numpy as np
import random
from numpy.random import default_rng
default_rng(seed=5)
idx = random.sample(range(1,50),10)
rng.ravel()[idx] = 0
rng


    [[15 19  6  4 16 16 10  3 16 10]
     [ 0  3  0 14  8 16  1  0 10 19]
     [ 0 16  2  7 15 11 18 15 18 16]
     [ 0  0  0  3 19 15  0  3  8 18]
     [15  5 10 17 13  6  0 19  5  0]]
```

Second (Is the embedding matrix [31,15)

```
x = default_rng(seed=2)
x= x.integers(1,20,(30,15))
default_rng(seed=2)
new_row = np.zeros((1,15),dtype=np.int64)
x_new=np.concatenate([new_row,x],axis=0)
print(x_new)
    [[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
     [16  5  3  6  8 16  9  2  7 12 16 14 19  4 17]
     [ 2 11  6  4 13  6 11  5  3 15  9 13 13 18  9]
     [ 5 13 18 19 17 13  8  8  1  4  7  7 12 10 14]
     [17 17 15 19  7 18 18  5  9 11 14 14  3 10  2]
     [19  4  9 17 10 13 10 17 12 13  9  8 12 10 15]
     [12  9 17  5  9 10 17  9 12  2 16  9 10  2 14]
     [13  7 15 10  2  5  5  2 10  1 10 14 12  9  6]
     [18  7 16  9  8 14 19 15 12  3 15 15  8  7  4]
     [19  4 10  4 15 12  4  3  2  1 17 16  8  2  6]
     [ 9 11 10 12 12 12 10  9 18 16 15  2 11 17 12]
     [ 4 10 11 19 11  5  3 14 19 11  2  1 15  6 10]
     [18  5 15  2  1  1  6 10  1 12 16 10  3 16  2]
     [10 19  7  9  5  7  5  1 15  8 19  7 15 10 12]
     [ 1 17  3 19  4 15  9 15  6  5 12  1  6 13 18]
     [ 9 19  6  2 13  4 19 11 19 15 14  2 16  4  2]
     [ 9  3 13 19 18 18 17  5 16  5  2 15 19 16 12]
     [19  2  3  5  2 12  1  8 10  9 12 16 17 16 15]
     [11 12 16  9  8 16 19  8 12  1 19 16  1  8 17]
     [13 11  3 14 12  4 10 11 11  6 10  3 12  1  1]
     [18 16 13 10  4  9  5  4  9 10 16 11  3  3 19]
     [ 3 18 13  5  9 13 12  7  8 14 12  2 14  9 17]
     [12 11 12  8 14  6 17 14  5 17  3 18  8  8 11]
     [ 1 19 17 14  2 15  8 19 15  6  4  5 12  9  9]
     [ 6 17 13  2 19  1  3  4 10 16 13  2 10 11 18]
     [ 5 15  9 17 16  3  6  4  4  2 16 16  9 19 15]
     [ 1 13 15 14 14 11 18 19  6  6 14  5  5 12  2]
     [ 3 15 13  1 14 14 11  6  4 10  4 17 17  5 19]
     [ 9 10  7 18  4  5  9 10  4 18 16 13 12 18  6]
     [ 5 19  2  7  2 13 18 14 17  6  2  1  1 17  5]
     [19  3  4  6  3 11  9  6 12 16 19 17 19 16 19]]
```

Comment: Please clarify exactly how your shown results are different from what you want to achieve.

Comment: I wat to achieve a matrix of shape [5,10,15], the shown results is 2 matrices the first one has shape [5,10] and the second [31,15]